# Set global text color?

Tags: latex, colors

I know that to use color in a document you have to load the package "color". But I can only find documentation on how to define color for a given part of the document... not what I want to do. What I do want is to define a global text color, that is used per default.

Is this possible? Can anyone tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 25):

If you use, for example

```
\color{red}
```

in your preamble, before `\begin{document}`, then the text should be red throughout your document unless you override with another `\color` declaration.